# Advantages of Prism without DI framework for WPF

Tags: wpf, dependency-injection, prism

I am working with other developers on a WPF application who are very strongly pro Prism and I just don't understand the benefits. I get the idea of modularity with a Dependency Injection framework and using an EventAggregator. However, without these two things are there any core advantages to using Prism?

Basically I don't know why I need to dynamically load the views and place them in regions when I already know during development where they will go and they will never change from that.

Everything I have found online states the advantages of DI as the only advantages of Prism. Is there anything I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My IMHO

Where your thoughts about PRISM are wrong:

- PRISM is *framework*. So, you can use *any* part of it independently. It's DI containers, navigation framework, EventAggregator, DelegateCommand, NotificationObject, modular structure, regions, and many other things.
- DI does *not* relate to PRISM in any way. This is *independently* thing. You can easily use Unity (or MEF, but this is not truly DI container) *without* PRISM. PRISM just provide some integration of everything.

My thoughts about PRISM:

- "they will never change from that" - if you know it already, go away from this project. If project will never change - it's dead. From my experience, if project lives - *anything* can be changed. Even unchangable things. I worked very close with one insurance company, and they said that one thing *will never change*. They had some hundreds of thousands clients. And after 5 (!!!) years it was changed... It was very cool. Thank God, I always think that *anything* can be changed.
- the other pro of PRISM is "standartization" - all standard classes have the same name, they have the same properties and methods, your project has standard structure etc.
- PRISM's regions provide some analogy of DI for XAML. Can you do that without it? Of course you can. But again - this is "standard" way. You can very easy jump to another project and you  will not study one another "poor man framework".

Again, this is *my IMHO*. For sure, I can be wrong..

Answer (score 1):

PRISM provides a framework to compose applications in a modular manner. So you don't have to inject your views into a Region but it makes it more flexible. You can more easily play with different views and inject them into your regions.

I agree that DI is probably the most used feature of PRISM and arguably the most compelling reason to use it. In general, it's not necessary to use PRISM, especially if your app is small enough but it does make it more flexible for changes down the road. Decoupling components is good and PRISM provides a means of achieving it (not the only means).

HTH.

Comment: For applications where you need dynamic changing I can understand. However, most applications don't need this. They know exactly what goes where. I think it is much easier to specify in the XAML your view. As I said I do like DI though.

Answer (score 0):

I do use Regions and Navigation heavily. It may not apply to your scenarios, but in my case I have mutliple views which I open in TabControl (via navigation). Ability to pass parameters (query string) and control targets (NavigationAware) is a big deal for me.

Consider you have UI with Customers and Orders. You see customer and his orders. You click on specific order and another page opens. Guess what, you can access Orders view with navigation like this:

1. /OrderView
2. /OrderView?OrderKey=123

First one will open your view. Second one will open and navigate to Order you need. You can also put link from order view to customer view

/CustomerView - will open new customers screen

/CustomerView?CustomerKey=123 - will open your customer OR navigate back into view you had open already.

If you care about scenarios like this - PRISM will help.

If your team uses regions on a same view - I don't see much benefit either. And I don't have regions like this.

Another example use:

I have MenuStackPanel with a region. Depending on users permissions application will load modules this user can use. When modules load - they register their pieces and populate menu with their options.